# Finding items with same properties in a collection

Tags: algorithm

I have a collection with many items in it. These items have some properties but let's say 2 of them are significant in this case; **Available** and **Priority**. Available is a simple bool property whereas priority can be any number ranging from 1 to 100. What I need to achieve is to find n number of items which are sequential, where all of them are Available (== true) and have the same priority.
I am not limited to using the collection only, meaning I may create additional data structures to speed up the lookup process (like a byte array showing the statuses of the items like: 101010001).

If I have to visualize it a bit:

1[99],0[80],1[60],1[60],0[60]

1 and 0 show the availability and the numbers in the brackets show the priority. I need to find 3rd and 4th item.

What's the fastest way to implement such an algorithm?

Note: This is certainly not a homework question.

**EDIT:** I can't change the order of the items, neither remove some of the items from the collection.

Comment: Store all available tasks in a separate collection and sort based on priority?

Comment: HashMap has the loopkup O(1). Can't say you can get better than this.

Comment: `which are sequential` - so you should not change the order?

Comment: @MBo Yes, I can't change the order.

Comment: You collection is always the same? Could it be changed? Do you need to make a single query with parameter `n`, or many queries with different parameters? Such details are important. For single search there is no need in additional structures, linear scan through your list/array is the most effective approach.

Comment: @MBo Collection is always the same, no additions or removals. I don't have to make a single query. As long as find n available items with the same priorities side by side quickly, I am free to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a `HashMap` to store the elements with avail as `true` only. Key of the HashMap will be the priority and value will be its count of occurrence.

Finally print out those key whose `value > 1`.

Hence you can complete this operation in `O(n)` time complexity, where n being the total number of elements.